# bootstrap not working in laravel5

Tags: php, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I followed [this turotial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/10) as basic laravel learning. I executed `composer require illuminate/html`. To import bootstrap in my project, in 'providers', I added

```
 Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

And in alaises, i added

```
'Form'=> Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
 'Html'=> Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
```

But the bootstrap does not seem to be working.

```
{!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label("name : ", "Your name") !!}
            {!! Form::text("username", null, ["class"=>"form-control"]) !!}
        </div>

 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

The text field does not stretch to the width of page, as it is supposed to.

Any idea why is it so? or any other alternative solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include link to bootstrap in your html template file.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "container">
            @yield("content")
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, i simply had not thought about it. Thank you.